# jQuery/JavaScript adding value of a button to total onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, addition, subtraction

I have a list of buttons with numeric values and a total number displayed on top of the page.

OnClicking one of the buttons (e.g. "Add 100"), I want the integer value of 100 to be added to the total points displayed. I want the total to update instantly versus the page having to refresh every time.

Do I have the right idea? Is this possible with JavaScript and jQuery or do I need to try something else?

Comment: Yes, entirely possible in jQuery or plain JavaScript. I would opt for jQuery if you want to get the job done fast.

Comment: You are on the right track. Show us some of the code you have so far and we can help you along some more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jquery:

http://jsfiddle.net/mYuRK/

**HTML**

```
<button value="100">100</button>
<button value="200">200</button>
<button value="300">300</button>
<div class="total"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var theTotal = 0;
$('button').click(function(){
   theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
    $('.total').text("Total: "+theTotal);        
});

$('.total').text("Total: "+theTotal);
```

Comment: Thats perfect, thank you! That's basically the html code I had for the buttons.

Comment: Actually, I tried this code because it looked the simplest and it's working on fiddle but not on my page. Here is my code:

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Add/Subtract Points - Brownie Points</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
 
var theTotal = 0;
$('button').click(function() {
    theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
    $('.total').text("Total: " + theTotal);
});

$('.total').text("Total: " + theTotal);
</script>

</head>
<body>
<button value="100">100</button>
<button value="200">200</button>
<button value="300">300</button>
<div class="total"></div>

</body>

</html>

Comment: I dont know if its the case in your source but this: `<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"; type="text/javascript"></script>` needs a `http://` and no `;` after the src

Answer (score 1):

Something like this :

```
<div>Total : <span id="total">0</span></div>
<input class="add" data-amount="100" type="button" value="Add 100" />
<input class="add" data-amount="10" type="button" value="Add 10" />
<input class="add" data-amount="50" type="button" value="Add 50" />
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.add').click(function() {
     $('#total').text(parseInt($('#total').text()) + parseInt($(this).data('amount')));
  });
})
```

[Working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/hdRT5/3/) and [docs for .data() here](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and [docs for .click() here](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example piece of code that should do the drink.

```
<div id="total">0</div>

<input id="clickme" type="button" value="click me!" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
       $('#clickme').on('click', function() {
          var number = parseInt($('#total').text());
          number+=100;
          $('#total').text(number);
       });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div>Total : <span id="total">0</span></div>
<button data-amount="10">Add 10</button>
<button data-amount="50">Add 50</button>
<button data-amount="100">Add 100</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').bind('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            $total = $("#total"),
            amount = $total.data("amount") || $total.text();

        amount += parseFloat($this.data('amount'));

        $total
            .data("amount", amount)
            .text(amount);
    });
});
```